# Java GregorianCalendar change TimeZone

Tags: java, date, timezone

I'm trying to set HOUR_OF_DAY field and change Timezone of the GregorianCalendar date object.

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+10"));
System.out.println("HOUR: " + date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
//date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("HOUR: " + date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Output:

```
HOUR: 16
HOUR: 23
```

For some reason value of HOUR_OF_DAY does not change after setting different timezone. But if I uncomment date.get for HOUR_OF_DAY, everything works exactly as it should

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+10"));
System.out.println("HOUR: " + date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // uncommenting this line will is changing the output
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("HOUR: " + date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Output:

```
HOUR: 16
HOUR: 13
```

How is this possible? Why .get method is changing object behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class inherits its [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method from `Calendar`, which has the following side effect:

> In lenient mode, all calendar fields are normalized.

This means that the `time` value and all fields are recomputed when `get` is called on a `Calendar` object.  This can lead to some unpredictable behavior, particularly when coupled with `setTimeZone`, which has some [documented buggy behavior](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4827490) of its own.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.ofHours( 10 )  ).withHour( 23 )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The legacy date-time classes including `GregorianCalendar` are a confusing. awkward, poorly-design mess. Avoid them. Now supplanted by the *java.time* classes. Specifically, `GregorianCalendar` is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

## Offset-from-UTC

You apparently want a moment with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of ten hours ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Define your desired offset.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 10 ) ;
```

> offset.toString(): +10:00

Get the current moment as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) with that offset.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( offset ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-02-15T16:44:44.216642+10:00

You want to override the hour to be `23`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt23 = odt.withHour( 23 ) ;
```

> odt23.toString(): 2018-02-15T23:44:44.216642+10:00

## Time zone

> I'm trying to set HOUR_OF_DAY field and change Timezone of the GregorianCalendar date object.

Nope, you are changing the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), not the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

Always better to use a time zone rather than a mere offset, *if you know for certain* the intended zone. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a certain region. With a time zone you can always determine the offset, but not vice-versa.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Brisbane" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment in a wall-clock time seen by the people of that zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Override the hour-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt23 = zdt.withHour( 23 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).