# set the timezone for the XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java

I have a the XMLGregorianCalendar instance and I need to set the timezone to the "America/New_York". The class has a method to set the timezone. AS the Greenwich Mean Time is 4 hours ahead of Eastern Time, does it set like this to the "America/New_York" timezone?

```
gregorianCalendar.setTimezone(-4);
```

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) the offset is in minutes.

Comment: Okay but how do I set the timezone America/New_York?

Comment: read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137428/java-gregoriancalendar-change-timezone and avoid using legacy time functions if possible.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes I set the offfset to the minutes and works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come with this solution lately and works fine for me.

```
Date date = format.parse(beginTime);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        int minutes = timeZone.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000 / 60;
        xmlGregCal.setTimezone(minutes);
```